# Default key binding is lost, how to restore it?

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings

I have been recently fiddling a lot with Emacs `org-mode`. In this process suddenly my key-binding for showing the agenda menu is lost, so I have to access it with `M-x org-agenda`.  The error I get when I press `C-c a` is " `C-c a` is undefined".

**How do I restore the original keybinding?**

Please answer the question with the following points in mind as I am trying to learn few things out of this problems.

- Where are these default key-bindings stored?
- What could I have done to cause the problem (So that I am more aware when I am doing it next time)?
- How do I restore it? I do not want to add a custom key binding in `.emacs` as `C-c a` usually there by default in org-more.

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible to know what you did to lose your original
binding, so here's the basic upshot.

- Your customizations (as with keybindings) will be stored in
  your
  [`init` file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html),
  and any other elisp files you call from it.
- If it was a temporary change (i.e., you didn't make changes to
  your `init` file manually or through `customize`), you can
  just restart Emacs.
- If you *did* make changes to your `init` file (intentionally
  or not), the problem will persist into new Emacs sessions.
- If you have no idea what code in the `init` file is causing
  you to lose your binding, do the following:

  - Start Emacs *without* your `init` file (`emacs -Q`) to
    confirm.
  - Recursively bisect your `init` file by successively
    commenting out halves until you isolate the problematic lines.

For a given keybinding, you can find out what it calls with `C-h k
KEY SEQUENCE`, (where `C-h k` calls `describe-key`).  For example,
you can try `C-h k C-c a`.

For a given command, you can find out the keybindings with `C-h f
FUNCTIONNAME` (where `C-h f` calls `describe-function`).  For your
case, you can try `C-h f org-agenda` to see what keybindings it has.

Note that the `org` manual's node on
[activation](http://orgmode.org/manual/Activation.html) *suggests*
using `C-c a` as a global keybinding to access `org-agenda`, but
you're under no obligation to use that particular binding.  If you
want to bind it again, you can follow it's suggestion with:

```
(global-set-key "\C-ca" 'org-agenda)
```

You can put that in your `scratch` buffer and evaluate it, but it
should be somewhere in your `init` file if you want it to persist
through Emacs sessions.

As an aside, the reason `C-c a` is not a hard and fast binding is
that it runs against
[keybinding conventions in Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Binding-Conventions.html),
one of which states:

> Don't define `C-c letter` as a key in Lisp programs. Sequences
>   consisting of `C-c` and a letter (either upper or lower case)
>   are reserved for users; they are the only sequences reserved for
>   users, so do not block them.

More generally, have a look at the Emacs manual node on
[Customizing Key Bindings](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Key-Bindings.html#Key-Bindings)
to find out how to bind keys as you like.