# I accidentally set a letter key to another command. How can I reset it?

Tags: key-bindings

In the past when this happened, I was able to google the answer with no problem, but this time nothing's coming up.

Comment: Letter keys are normally bound to `self-insert-command`, so you can bind it to that function again. Are you asking about a universal approach to rebind a key back to it's original keybinding?

Comment: Can anyone explain why this was downvoted? I spent 15 minutes googling and SO couldn't suggest an answer. A downvote seems incredibly unwelcoming, particularly since StackExchange owners have recently blogged about how they're trying to change the unwelcoming nature of the StackExchange sites.

Comment: I upvoted it. ;-) A guess is that someone thought it was too basic a question. But there is no question too basic. @DoMiNeLa10: Please consider posting your comment as an answer. OP: You can *accept* that answer, if you feel it's correct (which I think it is).

Comment: You are right that whoever voted down could have, for the benefit of the community, explained why this question is not written in an acceptable form for SE. Please read the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Basically it is preferred to write a complete question (not just in the subject of the post) and to phrase it in a manner that will be useful for the next member that searches for a solution. keep posting @MichaelTerry

Comment: I'll be interested to see if this question gets visibility in google for any of the queries I tried. My feeling is that the world would be a better place if every basic question had an answer at the top of the serps.

Comment: Is this different from [Default key binding is lost, how to restore it?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/26607/default-key-binding-is-lost-how-to-restore-it)

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, `self-insert-command` doesn't appear on that page, which is exactly what I needed.

Comment: @MichaelTerry It does suggest the more general method of running a new instance of Emacs and asking it which command the key is bound to; but the answer also covers so many other aspects that this solution for your specific problem might not be obvious.

Comment: @manandearth, So I read those guidelines. Where on that page does it say you need to redundantly post the question in the post body? If that adds nothing, what's the point? Also, it talks about "more likely to get an answer". It doesn't say it's unacceptable. It doesn't say it deserves downvotes. Is it possible that this sort of nitpickery is actually more unwelcoming than helpful?

Comment: @phils, Right, so this Q&A has a much better UI for someone who just needs the answer to this question and will be much better optimized for ranking in search engines for this Q&A.

Comment: FWIW https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/16738 is the nearest thing to a duplicate that I found in a quick search here. I think this Q&A is fine, though; terse though it may be.

Comment: @phils, Aha, good chance that was the post I found in the past. Unfortunately I'm of only average intelligence, so I could not find it again this time.

Comment: Well, I was searching for `self-insert-command` on the basis that it was the most likely way to turn up a duplicate :)  I can't comment on how easy it was to find if you didn't *already* know exactly what you were looking for.

Comment: Note that the description text of your question is more like a comment. Normally it should be the long version of your question. Stuff like the exact conditions under which the problem occurs, system information, a minimal example and instructions how to reproduce the problem. Maybe that was the reason why somebody down-voted your question.

Comment: Specifically in this case, adding that you know about `global-set-key`, but you aren't sure what to pass for `COMMAND` would make the question a lot clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Letter keys are normally bound to `self-insert-command`, so you can simply evaluate this:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "x") #'self-insert-command)
```

Of course, you'll have to replace that `x` with whatever key you want to rebind. You can eval this by yanking it into a scratch buffer, putting point after it and typing <kbd>C-x C-e</kbd> or you can enter it in the <kbd>M-:</kbd> prompt.

Comment: Or `M-x global-set-key` if it's a one-time problem.

Comment: @phils TIL `global-set-key` is `interactive`, I've always used `M-:` or the scratch buffer for it!

Comment: Ditto for `local-set-key`, for (usually) the major mode's keymap.